# Failed to load resource from bower_components even with correct file path

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser-sync

I'm running into some frustrating 404 errors while working on a web project. I'm using this file structure for my CSS and JS files:

```
bower_components
    bootstrap
        |dist
            |css
               | bootstrap.min.css
    angular
        |angular.min.js
    jquery
        |dist
            |jquery.min.js
dist
lib
    |farbtastic.js
node_modules
src
    |img
    |styles
    |scripts
    |view1
    |view2
    |index.html //running browserSync from this folder using this file as index
```

When I try to reference files in `index.html` using the appropriate syntax:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

I get a 404 "Failed to load resource" error.

The `../` syntax appears to be correct, and my console shows that it's looking in the correct location in `http://localhost:3000/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root directory of your application is the "src" folder. When you request bootstrap.min.css from "../bower_components/", you are telling the browser to go 1 level up. Because you are already at the root of the application, "../bower_component" is essentially doing the same as "bower_component".

You can:

```
1. move your index.html 1 level up
2. move your bower_components inside src
3. have some kind of build(gulp/grunt) to reorganize them in a way where the bower_components is within the root folder.
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. #2 worked for me, so that solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please how to do 3rd step using gulp? I tried but could not find solution for same. I am using single bootstrap installation for multiple projects. Just practice.

Comment: ```gulp.src("bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css").dest("dist/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/");```

Answer (score 1):

Since root directory of your application is `src` folder, you can still load from bower_components using the link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

configure you `browserSync.init`  this way

```
browserSync.init({
        server: {
                baseDir :"src",
                routes:{
                    "/bower_components" : "bower_components"
                }
        }
```